# Calculate with DAX measurements the number of repeated contacts from customers based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am working on a Power BI report, where based on the data, I should be able to calculare the Repeated contact rate for inbound calls. The data is on daily level. For the Repeated contact I should consider if the customer call on the same day more than 1x (this is for successfull calls), and if the customer call was abandon (not successfull, not reach the opertor) than not only the same day is considered but until the first successfull call (next days). The daily result shoud be agregated to weekly and monthly level.
The result should change accordingly what filter is applied on the report, it could be, country, queue, timeframe.

I created a measurement what works on daily level:

```
Unique =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Repeated Contact'[Customer] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Repeated Contact',
        'Repeated Contact'[Start date],
        'Repeated Contact'[Division Group],
        'Repeated Contact'[Division],
        'Repeated Contact'[Queue_Dep],
        'Repeated Contact'[Queue_Type],
        'Repeated Contact'[Name]
    )
)
```

but when I agregate on week or month i got less contact that if I add up manually the days, probably as agregated result is not add up the daily result, but do the calculation on the week or month timeframe.
This is only for the same day repeated contacts. I did not managed to came up with something for the abandoned contacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to aggregate this measure for several days, you will need a formula like this:

```
Unique (Agg) = 
SUMX ( 
   VALUES ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) , 
   [Unique]
)
```

This assumes that you have a calendar table set up that is connected to your data, as is best practice for any time intelligence calculations.

Without a dedicated calendar table you can try this measure that uses the available dates of your table in the current evaluation context (whatever that may be):

```
Unique (Agg) = 
SUMX ( 
   VALUES ( 'Repeated Contact'[Start date] ) , 
   [Unique]
)
```

Comment: Wooow, thank you @Marcus, the aggregation works well.

Comment: Excellent, happy to help, Peter!